# How to update my list in flutter when inserting a record?

Tags: flutter

When I save a record it doesn't update my list. Can anyone see something wrong in the code?

```
        Expanded(
          child: Obx( () =>
          LazyLoadScrollView(
                  onEndOfPage: () => controller.netxPage(),
                  isLoading: controller.lastPageAlgum,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: controller.posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return PostWidget(post: controller.posts[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Are you using any state management solutions? Like providers as an example...

Comment: I'm using Getx to manage widgets state

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is related to why your code is not updating, but you have a typo for the line

```
onEndOfPage: () => controller.netxPage(),
```

It should be

```
onEndOfPage: () => controller.nextPage(),
```

Let me know if that helped out

Answer (score 0):

```
 setState(() {
        items.addAll(List.generate(10, (index) => 'Inserted $index'));
      });
```

call  `setState(() { }` where you add record to your List